# taskkill command works with cmd but not working in java code to end process tree

Tags: java, process, pid, processbuilder, taskkill

when I type taskkill /f /t /pid xxx in Command Prompt, my process tree ends correctly. However, the code block below written in Java ends all processes in my process tree except one of them. Could you help me?

```
String pid = getPidWithSomeWay();
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","taskkill /f /t /pid " + pid);
Process p1 = pb1.start();
```

Also, I tried ending process tree implementation with ProcessHandle, but I am facing the same problem.

Comment: What doesn't it kill?   The process that spawns the cmd prompt?

Comment: It does not kill java.exe.

Comment: So just exit when the process 'p1' has completed.

Comment: Thank you anyway but I realized that the latest java.exe in the tasklist was my java program to kill the process tree. So, I think both ProcessBuilder and ProcessHandle implementations are working.